# How can I compare strings in Python?

Tags: python

Are there Python operators (or functions) equivalent to Perl lt (less than) and gt (greater than) operators used for string comparison ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can trivially `def lt(x,y): return x < y` although, these functions are already available in the `operator` module. Or are you asking about the `<` and `>` operators... Which definitely exist and work on strings...

Comment: You're better off describing what you actually want to do rather than asking for an equivalent of something in another language. You're relying on getting someone who understands Perl and Python and your use case well enough to tell you what the equivalent is.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well that was simple, i thought < and > could only be used for numeric comparison in Python, found out i was wrong with your hint.
Thank you

Comment: Python doesn't really know what "less than" means. It calls "magic" methods on objects that decide what the operation should be. So, add may add integers, concatentate lists and do memberwise addition on numpy arrays. These are all implemented by the objects themselves. See [Special Method Names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)

Answer (score 5):

Perl does not distinguish between numbers and strings. They are just scalars. Perl therefore has distinct operators for numeric comparison `< == >` and string comparison `lt eq gt`.

Python objects have distinct types like `int`, `float`, and `str`. The operators like `< == >` are overloaded to do the correct thing for that type. Comparison between two string objects will use string comparison.

This means that if you want to force string comparison, you must convert the arguments to string. For example, the Perl code `10 lt 42` would have to be expressed in Python as `str(10) < str(42)`. If you try to compare between objects of different types, you will get a TypeError – Python will not implicitly convert the objects.